# org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.mergeRequestConfig overrides the Default RequestConfig provided by HttpClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-httpclient-4.x

Spring Boot 2.7.14
Httpcomponents-client 4.5.14

Found this but it does the opposite of what we expect: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17184

[image]

HttpClient defaultRequestConfig:

[image]

The Builder populated with expected defaults from HttpClient:
But the System default:

[image]

Is used for comparison: (Wrong way round right?)

[image]

Getting back to

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory:
public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {

The REQUEST_CONFIG attribute is set to this newly overridden config.